# Share options between class instances in python

Tags: python

Why dictionary content shared between class instances, but strings not shared?

Test code:

```
class Config(object):
    file_names  = dict()
    file_name_1 = None
    file_name_2 = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not self.file_names:
            print "DEBUG: Config(): set initial values"
            self.file_names["0"] = None
            self.file_names["1"] = None

    def set_file_names(self, file_names):
        self.file_name_1     = file_names[0]
        self.file_names["0"] = file_names[0]
        self.file_name_2     = file_names[1]
        self.file_names["1"] = file_names[1]

class CommandLineParser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cfg = Config()
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.cfg.set_file_names(("file_1.log", "file_2.log"))
        print self.__class__.__name__, "FileName1 (str) :", self.cfg.file_name_1
        print self.__class__.__name__, "FileName1 (dict):", self.cfg.file_names["0"]

class LogProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cfg   = Config()
        self.cmdln = CommandLineParser()
        print  self.__class__.__name__, "FileName1 (str) :", self.cfg.file_name_1
        print  self.__class__.__name__, "FileName1 (dict):", self.cfg.file_names["0"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processor = LogProcessor()
```

Output:

```
DEBUG: Config(): set initial values
CommandLineParser FileName1 (str) : file_1.log
CommandLineParser FileName1 (dict): file_1.log
LogProcessor FileName1 (str) : None
LogProcessor FileName1 (dict): file_1.log
```

Is it a right way to share options between instances in dictionary attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`files_names` is a class attribute of your class `Config` so it is shared by all instances of this class. `file_name_1` and `file_name_2` are also initially class attributes (set to `None`) but you rebind them in instances inside the `set_file_names` method so they become instance attributes, private to each instance, at that time.

Your idea to use a class attribute which is a mutable container (`dict`) to contain configuration common to all instances and which can be updated dynamically is good.

If you still want to use the individual string attributes `file_name_1` and `file_name_2` but you want them to be shared between all instances, then you can do one of the following things:

- Rebind the *class* attribute instead of creating an instance attribute in `set_file_names` by using `Config.file_name_1 = whatever` instead of `self.file_name_1 = whatever`
- Make the `set_file_names` method a class method (use the `@classmethod` decorator) so that it will operate on the class, not on the instance.
- Do not instantiate the Config class at all, single it is meant to be a singleton anyway. Use `Config` instead of `Config()`.

Comment: Thanks! 
In my case config options must be used in four additional classes with default values if other not set, changing class attribute instead of instance attribute works fine.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not sure if in your case the Config needs to be singleton or not, the way to config dict to just one Config instance could be:

```
class Config(object):
    file_names  = None
    file_name_1 = None
    file_name_2 = None

    def __init__(self):
        if self.file_names is None:
            self.file_names = dict()
            ...
```

However, I strongly believe that its a better design to instantiate the Config only once in your application and pass the instance all around:

```
class CommandLineParser(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.cfg = config
        self.start()
```

In a more general terms, its always better to pass contextual information explicitly along.

Comment: +1 to instantiating the `Config` class once and passing it around as context information

Comment: Yes, in first time my code looks like this, but in additional tasks config options were to be used in other classes with run from LogProcessor or import from this module without running of LogProcessor and command line parsing. Independent config class with default values, that can be easily used from over modules, seemed to me better, but `__init__(self, config = Config())` in other classes works fine too. Thank you.